# Magento 2 Create an order using Integration token in REST API

Tags: magento2, admin, rest-api, place-order, integration

I want to place orders on behalf of a customer. I have an integration token for this. I have followed the below steps.

1. Create Empty Cart = POST `/V1/carts` (Passing customer Id as param)
2. Add product to cart = POST `"/V1/carts/".$quote_id."/items"` (Passing product data)
3. Get Shipping methods = POST `"/V1/carts/".$quote_id."/estimate-shipping-methods"`
4. Set shipping and billing = POST `"V1/carts/".$quote_id."/shipping-information"`

The above steps are working fine. Now I need to set the payment method and place the order. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the below steps to place an order on behalf of a customer using integration token.Now it is working fine.

1. Create Empty Cart:  /V1/carts/mine => POST with payload {'customer_id':{customerId}}. It returns the cartId
2. Add Products to cart: /V1/carts/{cartId}/items => POST Request
3. Get Cart Totals: /V1/carts/{cartId}/totals => GET Request
4. Estimate Shipping methods: /V1/carts/{cartId}/estimate-shipping-methods  => POST Request ( It list all availble shipping methods)
5. Set Billing and Shipping: /V1/carts/{cartId}/shipping-information  => POST Request (It returns the availble payment methods)
6. Set Payment and place order: /V1/carts/mine/payment-information  => POST Request (It returns the Order increment Id)
7. To get the order Details: /V1/orders => GET Request with search criteria

searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={IncrementId}